# Error publishing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 site to Azure from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a preexisting **ASP.NET Core 3.0** application which is successfully deployed to an **Azure App Service** (using the `AspNetCoreModuleV2` module). After upgrading the app to (today's release of) **ASP.NET Core 3.1**, the application builds and runs correctly on my local version of **IIS Express**. When I attempt to publish to the Azure App Service using (today's release of) **Visual Studio 16.4**, however, I receive the following error:

> Assets file 'C:\Project\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

#### Notes

- My `csproj` file's `<TargetFramework>` is correctly set to `netcoreapp3.1`.
- All `<PackageReference>`'s to `Microsoft.AspNetCore`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, and `Microsoft.Extensions` have been updated to `3.1.0`
- I have cleaned my solution, and even nuked my `obj` folder to ensure there aren't any lingering references.
- This error is being generated from the `3.1.100` version of `Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets`.

I get that *something* is still hanging onto the **.NET Core 3.0** dependencies. But it's unclear why that's only causing problems during *deployment*. Is **Azure App Service** not yet ready for **.NET Core 3.1**? Or is this an issue with the dependency resolution targets?

Comment: The docs [show how to explicitly select the .NET Core SDK version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-aspnet-core-30-to-azure-app-service). Have you tried that? Does the 3.1 SDK appear in the list?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: This project isn't published using **Azure Pipelines** yet. That said, this _does_ remind me that there's _also_ a `<TargetFramework>` setting in the `pubxml` profile that **Visual Studio** relies on, which I spaced on. Oops! Changing that to `netcoreapp3.1` to match the `csproj` target resolves the immediate issue. (This introduces a new issue with **Azure App Service** itself tripping on the target, but that can probably be resolved by using a self-contained deployment, similar to the link you provided.) Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Aah, timezone differences ...

Comment: Well thank goodness for finding this question (and answer). I am starting to get pretty frustrated with adopting bleeding edge MS changes (on their recommendation and encouragement) only to keep running into issues like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The immediate issue—as identified in the original question—has to do with there being *two* places where `<TargetFramework>` is set:

1. The **project file** (e.g., `csproj`)
2. The **publishing profile** (i.e., `pubxml`)

The `<TargetFramework>` must be updated in *both* locations, and they must match *exactly*. Otherwise, the publishing won't be able to find its targets in the `project.assets.json` file, which is built based on the `<TargetFramework>` in the `csjproj` file.

> ***Note:*** You may well expect the `pubxml` file to defer to the `<TargetFramework>` set in the `csproj` file, but that is *not* the case.

#### Text Editor

To make this modification via a text editor,

1. Open the `~/Properties/PublishProfiles` folder.
2. Open the `*.pubxml` you wish to edit.
3. Modify the value of `<TargetFramework>` to `netcoreapp3.1`:

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

#### Visual Studio 2019

To make this modification via the **Visual Studio 2019** IDE,

1. Click the gear icon <kbd>⚙</kbd> on the *Web One Click Publish* toolbar (it's to the right of the publish icon).
2. Assuming the *Target Framework* is *not* set to `netcoreapp3.1`, click the edit icon next to it.
3. Ensure that the *Target Framework* is set to `netcoreapp3.1`.
4. Click *Save*.

> ***Warning:*** When using the IDE, you may run into a problem here. When editing the profile you'll likely see the *new* value from your project file (i.e., `netcoreapp3.1`) already selected. When you click *Save*, however, it will revert back to the *original* value (e.g., `netcoreapp3.0` in my case). This is because you didn't actually *change* the value in the interface, which Visual Studio mistakes for there not being a change to the *underlying* values. If you temporarily toggle another value (e.g., *Configuration*), then Visual Studio will recognize that a change has occurred, and *both* values will be updated in the `*.pubxml` file.

#### Acknowledgements

Thank you, again, to [@PanagiotisKanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) for pointing me in the right direction ([see comments on original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59171630/error-publishing-an-asp-net-core-3-1-site-to-azure-from-visual-studio-2019/59184689#comment104566301_59171630)).

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution! I was struggling with this when I tried to publish last night and it just didn't make any sense. In the publish wizard it always had 3.1 selected as the target so I figured it was ok, but once I opened the `pubx` file as you explained it was still on 3.0. Very frustrating. Honestly, I've had nothing but weird, obscure and completely show stopping bugs and issues since VS 16.3 and .NET Core 3.0 were released. Thanks again!

Comment: Idk if you're getting this too, but it's quite lovely how when you tell it to publish as framework-dependent, it decides to publish the entire framework along with it. A publish that should be 1 min or so, is now 15+ min...

Comment: FYI: Since I originally posted this, **Microsoft** has updated the **Azure App Services** to provide native support for **.NET Core 3.1**. Given that, I've removed the warning regarding the `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure` message from my original message. Previously, this necessitated publishing a fully self-contained distribution of your application. (That said, there's usually a 2-3 day lag time between a new version of **.NET Core** dropping, and it being integrated into the **Azure App Service** environment, so this is useful to be aware of in future updates.)

Comment: Nice, I had only updated the framework version in the project properties and didn't even cross my mind about the .pubxml file. This was causing my publish to hang, after updating the .pubxml to "netcoreapp3.1" it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Open Project folder;

- Navigate to folder Properties>>PublishProfiles
- Open file FolderProfile.pubxml then change version **3.0** to **3.1**

  netcoreapp3.1
- Finally, rebuild your application before publishing

Comment: Good call on providing explicit instructions for modifying the `pubxml` file manually, and especially given the goofiness of modifying these values via the **Visual Studio 2019** GUI. I've incorporated these details into my original answer so this option is explicitly explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error from a fresh new net5.0 project in VS2019 (ASP.NET Core Web Application template) when using the VS web-publisher. The solution is as follows:

1. Open file: `{project}\Properties\PublishProfiles\{project} - Web Deploy.pubxml`
2. Add the following line inside the `<PropertyGroup>` element:

   `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`

The element was missing entirely - great work MS

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<PackageReferenceInclude="Microsoft.AspNetCore"Version="2.2.0" />
 to 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
```

works for me.

Comment: For **ASP.NET Core 3.1**, all `Microsoft.AspNetCore` libraries should be updated to `3.1.0`, as per Microsoft’s v3.1 release notes. Your approach may be a valid fix for similar problems in **ASP.NET Core 2.2**, assuming that the error wasn’t caused by a mismatch between your `csproj` and `pubx` files, as it was in my case.

Comment: The version of two above mentioned packages are currently in 2.2.0 and marked as latest version.

Comment: @Libertad, you need to upgrade your visual studio installation to version 16.4.0 to see latest dot net core 3.1 version

Comment: @navule my VS is uptodate. Aabove packages are just nuget package. Take a look at this:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore 
and see its latest version